# Is there a tool for automatically checking English grammar?

Tags: automation, text-editing, spell-check, grammar

I need to run through a document and check that it contains proper English grammar. My toolset for spell-checking for words include ispell and OpenOffice, but they seem only to do spell-checking.

Even though OpenOffice was talking about grammar I didn't manage to get it to find grammar faults, only spelling errors.

I'd like to check some basic rules such as "a/an articles" etc.

Comment: When you find one, copy and paste your title into the tool then edit the title with the results.

Comment: @Russ Warren The comment is a bit mean, isn't it?

Comment: Gotta give that a try when I check out the tools =)

Comment: @Russ: Ziinnngggg! But do give some indication that such comments are lighthearted. SuperUser should be inviting, and that kind of stuff can get taken badly if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org/). From the site:

> An Open Source language checker for
>   English, German, Polish, Dutch, and
>   other languages. This is a rule-based
>   language checker that will find errors
>   for which a rule is defined in its XML
>   configuration files. Rules for more
>   complicated errors can be written in
>   Java. You can think of LanguageTool as
>   a tool to detect errors that a simple
>   spell checker cannot detect, e.g.
>   mixing up there/their, no/now etc. It
>   can also detect some grammar mistakes.
>   It does not include spell checking

Comment: I tried LanguageTool a couple of years ago where it really hauged my system's resources. I also found consistency issues in terms of what it marks and what it omits

Comment: Most apps are continually updated and improved. Give it another try, maybe it will fit your needs this time around :)

Comment: That was quite fine for my purposes.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!